# Trying to find a simple example of pstool that compiles

Tags: pdftex, psfrag, pstool

There have been many posts on this site either requesting simple examples illustrating the `pstool` package, or providing (often not-simple) ones. I've tried all of them and none of them compile for me. I've also tried to read `pstools.sty`, which came with my installation, but unfortunately it contained no simple examples. It seems that the following MWE is about as simple as one could possibly get.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstool}
\EndPreamble
\begin{document}
\psfragfig{trial}{%
  \psfrag{[Mp]}{$M_a$}%
}
\end{document}
```

Yet it throws all sorts of inexplicable errors, and fails to compile.
I'm running the `pdflatex` that comes with texlive 2016, installed in the recommended way, on a Linux 64 bit machine, Ubuntu 16.04.

To compile I'm using the command

> pdflatex -shell-escape

There's talk on the web about a file called `pstool-statusfile.txt`, which I don't understand, but I've touch'ed it, just in case, it's zero size before and after compilation. The file `trial.eps` was downloaded from

[the CTAN example site for pstools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pstool/example)

I'd love to hear if anybody can get this code to run, if so, how? if not, why not?

Here's the relevant portion of the `.log` file:

```
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
(.//trial.tex) <trial.eps>
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.21  \includegraphics [] {trial}


LaTeX Warning: Command \b invalid in math mode on input line 21.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.21  \includegraphics [] {trial}

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.21  \includegraphics [] {trial}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21  \includegraphics [] {trial}

Preview: Tightpage -32891 -32891 32891 32891
[1] (.//trial-pstool.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on .//trial-pstool.dvi (1 page, 2232 bytes).
Transcript written on .//trial-pstool.log.

(./pstool-statusfile.txt)

Package pstool Warning: Execution failed during process:
  latex -shell-escape -output-format=dvi -output-directory="./" -interaction=no
nstopmode  "trial-pstool.tex"
This warning occurred on input line 9.


=== pstool: end processing ===

[1
Non-PDF special ignored!{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/upd
map/pdftex.map}] (./myExample.aux)
```

Answer (score 2):

note that you need `pdflatex --shell-escape` to enable the psfrag processing.

When running your MWE the log complained of missing packages so I added tikz and its calc library then it worked as expected. `trial.eps` here is a copy of `example-image.eps` that is in tex distributions (if I left it as example-image ot ran without error but found the png file rather than eps so coukd not do the replacement

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\addtolength\textwidth{1in}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-.5in}
\EndPreamble
\begin{document}

\includegraphics{trial}

\psfragfig{trial}{%
  \psfrag{Image}{$M_a$}%
}
\end{document}
```

here I show the image included directly and with the psfrag replacement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much David.   I ran your file as a test on my own eps file, with just one silly psfrag substitution.     The result, remarkably, was that  my silly change was ignored, but *all* of my *actual* psfrag substitutions (which were written in a .tex file with an unrelated name) were made to David.pdf.   The only way this could have happened is if the `psfragfig` command looked thru *all* of the .tex files in my cwd, and found every psfrag command that related to the text strings in the .eps file named in David.tex.     Amazing and scary.

Comment: @LeoSimon whatever it did, it didn't do that:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I have a similar problem with some matlabfrag exported eps figure. As a test, I have tested with some other graphics(tex and eps inputs for psfragfig) input and they seem to work. Only this figure and the related pstool files are creating problem, exactly the above explained problem. Adding also \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{calc} did not help me. I have spent some time but could not find the reason, do you also have any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, isn't it also very strange that the other files exported in the same manner are working fine and only this specific one is creating the problem

Comment: @UmutTabak there are lots of cases where psfrag can not "find" text in an eps file it all depends on the way text is encoded in the file (and if it is encoded as text at all rather than as stroked paths.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am not completely sure what the problem is. But, the eps files are all MATLAB exported figures and I believe, as an educated guess, not sure though, the text is encoded in the same way. The strange thing is that one figure is working with it and the other fails.

Comment: @UmutTabak sorry but the site mechanics don't really support discussion under old questions, if you can make a reproducible example feel free to ask a new question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, ok, you are right. Could please follow my question with the title pstool and matlabfrag ambiguity?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, here is the link to the question with files: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356625/pstool-psfragfig-and-matlabfrag-ambiguity